# 'echo [A-Z]*' matches lower-case filenames as well?

Tags: bash, filename

I am working on the root directory and want to print directory entries starting with an upper-case letter.

```
$ echo [A-Z]*
Applications Library Network System Users Volumes bin cores dev etc home installer.failurerequests net private sbin tmp usr var vm
```

The result confuses me because I wasn't expecting 
`cores dev etc home installer.failurerequests net private sbin tmp usr var vm` to match my pattern.

How can I write a glob pattern that only matches upper-case letters?

Comment: When the [expletive deleted] did that change? ... no wonder I've had to recover so many files from backup recently!  When I use [A-Z] I _expect_ it to do exactly what I asked, not some Windows-centric interpretation of it, and certainly not without warning!  Unix-type system are NOT supposed to be case insensitive!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's because the glob pattern `[A-Z]` does not generally correspond to uppercase letters. Specifically it expands according to

> the  current locale's collating sequence and character set

If you want files starting with an upper case letter, you can use

```
echo [[:upper:]]*
```

or set the locale explicitly

```
(LC_COLLATE=C; echo [A-Z]*)
```

or use the bash `globasciiranges` shell option

```
(shopt -s globasciiranges; echo [A-Z]*)
```

See the `Pattern matching` section of `man bash`

Comment: related (but different): if you use `shopt -s nocaseglob`, glob expansion is case-insensitive even for non-range parts of the pattern.  e.g. `echo DeV*` will match `dev`.  This is a handy setting if you often work with files with inconsistent case.